# Break Active Finder Tab Into New Window with Applescript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write an applescript to break the active Finder tab into a new window. I am able to do this with Chrome using:

```
on moveActiveTabToNewWindow()
  tell application "Google Chrome"
    set theURL to URL of active tab of window 1
    close active tab of window 1
    make new window
    set URL of active tab of window 1 to theURL
  end tell
end moveActiveTabToNewWindow
```

However, as far as I can tell Finder tabs are not accessible via Applescript. Is this possible? I'm on OS X Mavericks 10.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating tabs is not accessible directly but you could do it manually. In other words we can close that tab and then open a new window and replicate what you saw in that tab, just like you did in your Google Chrome example.

Here's some code. This code is basic. Just like I got the "target" property from the Finder window, you could get other properties too and replicate them in the new window to really do a more complete job of replicating the tab. You'll probably want to duplicate the bounds and view options at least.

Good luck.

```
-- get the target of the front tab
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    tell window 1 to set t to target
end tell

-- close that tab
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "w" using command down
end tell

-- make a new window and set its target
tell application "Finder"
    set w to make new Finder window at front
    tell w to set target to t
end tell
```